# Split multiple strings in multiple columns in a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, split

I have following matrix with numbers of 0 and 1 with always the same number of strings per column, but also containing columns with only one string. I would like to to split each number into separate columns, that only one number per column and row occurs. But I would like to leave the columns with only one string as it is:

```
r1 <- c("0","001","0001","01","100")
r2 <- c("1","001","0001","10","100")
r3 <- c("0","100","1000","10","010")
r4 <- c("0","010","0100","10","001")
r5<- c("0","010","0010","10","001")

n.mat <- rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
```

The output:

```
r1 <- c("0","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","1","0","0")
r2 <- c("1","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","1","0","1","0","0")
r3 <- c("0","1","0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","0","1","0")
r4 <- c("0","0","1","0","0","1","0","0","1","0","0","0","1")
r5 <- c("0","0","1","0","0","0","1","0","1","0","0","0","1")

n.mat_new <- rbind(r1,r2,r3,r4,r5)
```

My code, but it crashes, because of the columns with only one string:

```
n.mat <- do.call(cbind, apply(n.mat, 2, function(x) {
  tmp <-strsplit(x, '')
  t(sapply(tmp, `[`, 1:max(lengths(tmp))))
}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for `apply` or `paste` for this specific problem. Simply `t`ranspose the matrix, split all the strings, and re-construct the matrix according to the number of rows in the original matrix.

```
matrix(unlist(strsplit(t(n.mat), "")), nrow = nrow(n.mat), byrow = TRUE)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
# [1,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
# [2,] "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "1"  "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
# [3,] "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"  
# [4,] "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"  
# [5,] "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"
```

If you want further optimizations, you can do something like the following, which will retain the `rownames`

```
matrix(unlist(strsplit(t(n.mat), "", TRUE), use.names = FALSE), 
       nrow = nrow(n.mat), byrow = TRUE, 
       dimnames = list(rownames(n.mat), NULL))
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
# r1 "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
# r2 "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "1"  "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
# r3 "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"  
# r4 "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"  
# r5 "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"
```

---

By avoiding `apply`, you're only calling `strsplit` once, so you're going to notice much better performance if you have a lot of rows to process.

On my Chromebook (so these times are likely to be slow to begin with) testing with 10,000 rows, I get the following:

```
nrow(n.mat)
# [1] 10000

bench::mark(am_opt(), am(), gki(), jay(), check = FALSE)
# # A tibble: 4 x 13
#   expression     min  median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time
#   <bch:expr> <bch:t> <bch:t>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm>
# 1 am_opt()    28.3ms  40.1ms     27.4     2.75MB     0       14     0      511ms
# 2 am()        36.1ms  41.2ms     24.6     2.75MB     0       13     0      528ms
# 3 gki()      220.3ms 229.4ms      4.39    3.43MB     0        3     0      683ms
# 4 jay()      975.8ms 975.8ms      1.02    3.51MB     1.02     1     1      976ms
# # … with 4 more variables: result <list>, memory <list>, time <list>, gc <list>
```

I didn't benchmark Karthik's answer because just running it once took more than 1 minute.

```
system.time(karthik())
#    user  system elapsed 
#  81.341   0.000  81.343
```

Where the functions are directly copied from the other answers:

```
am_opt <- function() {
  matrix(unlist(strsplit(t(n.mat), "", TRUE), use.names = FALSE), 
         nrow = nrow(n.mat), byrow = TRUE, 
         dimnames = list(rownames(n.mat), NULL))
} 
am <- function() matrix(unlist(strsplit(t(n.mat), "")), nrow = nrow(n.mat), byrow = TRUE)
gki <- function() matrix(unlist(apply(n.mat, 1, strsplit, split = "")), nrow(n.mat), byrow=TRUE)
jay <- function() t(apply(n.mat, 1, function(x) el(strsplit(Reduce(paste0, x), ""))))
karthik <- function() bind_rows(apply(n.mat, 2, strsplit, split = '')) %>% t
```

Comment: Thanks again for your answer, do you also have a solution if I want to keep the column names, meaning to split one column into 4 additional columns should lead to: V1_1, V1_2, V1_3, V1_4 as column names?

Comment: @Luker354, I'd just use `nchar` on one row to create the column names. Something like this should create the pattern that I think you want: `nc <- nchar(n.mat[1, ]); paste0("V", rep(seq_along(nc), nc), "_", sequence(nc))`. Use `colnames` to apply the column names to the output.

Comment: Ok perfect, thank you very much. it worked

Answer (score 1):

Collapse `paste0` using `Reduce` and use `strsplit` on `""`.

```
t(apply(n.mat, 1, function(x) el(strsplit(Reduce(paste0, x), ""))))
#    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
# r1 "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
# r2 "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "1"  "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
# r3 "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"  
# r4 "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"  
# r5 "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(apply(n.mat, 2, strsplit, split = '')) %>% t
   [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
r1 "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
r2 "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "1"  "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
r3 "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"  
r4 "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"  
r5 "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strsplit` in `apply`, `unlist` the result and create with this a `matrix`.

```
matrix(unlist(apply(n.mat, 1, strsplit, split = "")), nrow(n.mat), byrow=TRUE)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13]
#[1,] "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
#[2,] "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "1"  "0"   "1"   "0"   "0"  
#[3,] "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "1"   "0"  
#[4,] "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"  
#[5,] "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "0"  "0"  "1"  "0"  "1"  "0"   "0"   "0"   "1"
```